# How to replace the letters of a sting to anther assigned value

Tags: php, algorithm, function

Am trying to in-script a sentence that contain strings. what i want to achieve is replacing the letters of the stings with another assigned value.

exmaple:

Value: **a  b  c  d  e  f  g  h  i  j  k  l  m  n  o  p  q  r  s  t  u  v  w  x  y  z**

Assign Value: **z  y  x  w  v  u  t  s  r  q  p  o  n  m  l  k  j  i  h  g  f  e  d  c  b  a**

"a" assigned to "z" and "b" assigned to "y" respectively in a sentence each time the sentence is run on the script.

INPUT: how are you brother?

OUTPUT: sld ziv blf yilghvi?

I want to write this script in PHP please someone should point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 2):

Cause `str_replace` has problem with array replace ordering. so you can use this function to do it:

```
function change_text($text){
    $search = range('a','z');
    $replace = range('z','a');
    $result = '';
    foreach (str_split($text) as $index => $char){
        if($found = array_search($char,$search)){
            $result .= $replace[$found];
        }else{
            $result .= $char;
        }
    }
    return $result;
}


echo change_text("how are you brother?"); // result  sld aiv blf yilgsvi?
```

[demo](https://3v4l.org/jRQYm)

Comment: There is still a small problem in `$found = array_search($char,$search)`. It evaluates to false when it gets `a`. Hence, I personally don't prefer assignment and condition check in the same line.

Comment: Even simpler: https://3v4l.org/bK9UJ and with fixed `a` issue

Answer (score 2):

**Snippet:**

```
function change_text($text){
   $replacement_map = array_merge(
                            array_combine( range('a','z'), range('z','a')),
                            array_combine( range('A','Z'), range('Z','A'))
                        );
   $length = strlen($text);
   for($i = 0;$i < $length; ++$i){
       if(!isset($replacement_map[ $text[$i] ])) continue; // skip characters that don't require replacing
       $text[$i] = $replacement_map[ $text[$i] ]; // replace current character with the desired one
   }

   return $text;
}



echo change_text("how are you brother?");
```

**Demo:** https://3v4l.org/D1j1c

**Algorithm:**

- Above code works for both lowercase and uppercase letters.
- We build a map(associative array) of an alphabetic character with it's required destination character which looks like below:

**Map(associative array):**

```
array (
  'a' => 'z',
  'b' => 'y',
  'c' => 'x',
  'd' => 'w',
  'e' => 'v',
  'f' => 'u',
  'g' => 't',
  'h' => 's',
  'i' => 'r',
  'j' => 'q',
  'k' => 'p',
  'l' => 'o',
  'm' => 'n',
  'n' => 'm',
  'o' => 'l',
  'p' => 'k',
  'q' => 'j',
  'r' => 'i',
  's' => 'h',
  't' => 'g',
  'u' => 'f',
  'v' => 'e',
  'w' => 'd',
  'x' => 'c',
  'y' => 'b',
  'z' => 'a',
  'A' => 'Z',
  'B' => 'Y',
  'C' => 'X',
  'D' => 'W',
  'E' => 'V',
  'F' => 'U',
  'G' => 'T',
  'H' => 'S',
  'I' => 'R',
  'J' => 'Q',
  'K' => 'P',
  'L' => 'O',
  'M' => 'N',
  'N' => 'M',
  'O' => 'L',
  'P' => 'K',
  'Q' => 'J',
  'R' => 'I',
  'S' => 'H',
  'T' => 'G',
  'U' => 'F',
  'V' => 'E',
  'W' => 'D',
  'X' => 'C',
  'Y' => 'B',
  'Z' => 'A',
)
```

- Now, we just loop over `$text` character by character and check if the character is present in our map. If yes, we replace it with the new destination character, else leave it as is and return the result.

Comment: thanks for real problem you notice to me. I update my answer to do exact response :)